# How to make a private chat between 2 users in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have Blog app built with Rails and on a post created by a user(`Author`) I have a  "Request a chat" button.

I want to build a small function on that post page that when `User A` presses that button, the page will redirect to or open a chatbox that connect `User A` with user `Author`?

`Author` is a devise registered user and `User A` is not.

**How would I build something like that? Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

I think it's weird having a devise registered user and a non devise user unless you mean User A is just an unregistered guest. Either way, it's not a big deal and it can be done.

The way you would put together that system is as follows:

```
    OpenChat             # your new data model
    OpenChatsController  # your new controller
```

"Request a chat" would create a new OpenChat object, with author and guest A foreign keys. If User A is a guest, you can store a cookie "password" in their browser but generally it's only advisable if the conversation is brief and security isn't a big deal.

Then you would be able to check if there is an open chat between the two users and display it in any page you want, and display messages appropriately.

You will need to look up how to setup a basic chat system (there are a million answers out there that will take you step by step) as that's beyond the scope of this question.

If you are new to Rails, I also recommend Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial:
https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Any gem for this kind of task or any blogs/tutorials that would help me get started?

Comment: Apart from the above mentioned Michael Hartl's blog. This is the official Action Cable guide -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html . It may also help to have a read up on Web Sockets